# Do the zeros of a smooth nonlinear function form a manifold?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, nonlinear-analysis

I am interested in knowing whether the zero locus of a nonlinear function forms a manifold. In essence, I am looking for an extension of the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem).

The preimage theorem, in simple terms, requires a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that the derivative $Df_x: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ at any point
$$
x\in\mathcal{M} := \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n ~|~ f(x) = 0 \}
$$
is surjective.
The theorem then states that the set $\mathcal{M}$ is a manifold, and that the tangent space $T_x \mathcal{M}$ for every $x\in\mathcal{M}$ is given by
$$
T_x \mathcal{M} = \ker(Df_x).
$$

I am curious if we can relax the assumptions on both $f$ and its derivative $Df_x$.
My intuition is that it should be sufficient to demand that $f$ is continously differentiable and that $Df_x$ has constant rank for all $x\in G$, where $G$ is an open neighborhood of $\mathcal{M}$.

My thoughts are the following:
Under these assumptions, in a neighborhood of $x\in\mathcal{M}$ the function $f$ "looks like" $Df_x$.
Since $Df_x$ is a matrix, the kernel $\ker(Df_x)$ forms a manifold.
And since $Df_x$ resembles $f$ locally, also $\ker(Df_x)$ should resemble $\mathcal{M}$ locally.
The assumption on constant rank of $Df_x$ then should ensure that the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ has constant dimension.

To illustrate this further, take a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, ~ x \mapsto Ax$ with a matrix $A$ that has a nontrivial kernel.
As $\ker(A) = \mathcal{M}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is clearly a manifold.
But the preimage theorem can not be applied in this situation, since $Df_x = A$ is not surjective.

Comment: No the vanishing set may have some singular point for example the vanishing set of $f(x,y) = y^2 - x^2(x+1)
$ which is smooth real value function which has vanishing set called nodal curve. easy to see the rank of the differential is not constant everywhere especially it's 1 dimension at each point other than origin.

Comment: The result you want is called the preimage theorem or regular level set theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot! I looked up the theorem, and it is kind of what I am looking for, but it is rather restrictive. For example, for a linear map $x mapsto Ax$ with the quadratic matrix $A$ which does not have full rank, the theorem can not be applied. But clearly, $\ker(A)$, i.e. the set $f^{-1}(0)$, is a submanifold. Are you familiar with a generalization of the preimage theorem which does not need the (strict) notion of regular values?

Comment: Possibly interesting exercise: For every closed (!) subset $F$ of Euclidean space, there exists a smooth, real-valued function whose zero set is $F$.

Comment: Your Question could easily become the kind of content that Math.SE seeks to "collect and curate" if you would provide some *context* for your problem formulation.  What about this problem interests you enough to take the time to post it here?  What research did you undertake before posting?

Comment: I don’t really understand the downvote. The question seems fine to me now.

Comment: @Stephen There has been a significant edit yesterday, if you look at the history of revisions

Comment: @Didier Yes, I was hoping the downvoter would see the edit and consider removing the downvote (though I admit perhaps my comment was a bit unclear).